# get element.innerHTML via pure JS from tablerow//<tr onClick(myFunction>

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, innerhtml

I am trying to enable a pop-up window with information on the clicked table element.
Therefore I wanna get the element ID of the clicked element. Thanks :D

### **Problem**

*I always get the same ID//table element no matter which table entry I click.*

**HTML Page with a table which displays data from the database**

```html
{%extends 'main/base.html'%}
{%block main%}
<div class="container-xxl d-flex justify-content-center">
   <div class="container-fluid" style='background-color:aquamarine;'></div>
   <div class="container-fluid" style='background-color:rgba(190, 90, 230, 0.308); height:10em;'></div>
   <div class="container-fluid" style='background-color:aquamarine;'></div>
</div>
<div class="container-xxl d-flex justify-content-center">
   <form action='' method="POST">
      {%csrf_token%}
      <input type='text' name='isbn' placeholder="ISBN-13 Number...">
      <button type='submit'>Add</button>
   </form>
</div>
<div class="container-xxl d-flex justify-content-center" id='table'>
   <table class='table table-hover'>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Kategorie</th>
            <th>Seitenzahl</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         {%for book in book_table%}
         <!--tr onClick()-->
            <tr onClick='get_element_ID()'>
               <td id='ID'>{{book.id}}</td>
               <td>{{book.title}}</td>
               <td>{{book.author}}</td>
               <td>{{book.kategorie}}</td>
               <td>{{book.seitenzahl}}</td>
            </tr>
         {%endfor%}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <p>footer</p>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tfoot>
   </table>
</div>
<script>
   function get_element_ID(){
      var id = (this).document.getElementById('ID');
      console.log(id);
      
   }
</script>
{%endblock main%}
```

**Picture of HTML Page with Table**

[image]

**Picture of console log output**

[image]

Comment: change this code ```<td id='ID'>{{book.id}}</td>``` to this ```<td id='{{book.id}}'>{{book.id}}</td>```

Comment: I changed it like you recommended, but now i get always _null_ in the console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the HTML DOM u can't have more than 1 item with the same id, for all of your td tags the id is ID, so if u change the `<td id="ID"> with <td id={{book.id}}>` , each td must have the correct id.

You are getting ID 1 all the time because when you do `getElementByID("ID")` the DOM returns the first element it finds with that ID, since there should be no more.

Comment: oh yeah , thanks for the hint !
I have done so , but I know get the value _null_

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned above the issue was the rather silly mistake that the requested ID in `getElementById('ID')` was always the same.

### This know works like it should:

```
{%extends 'main/base.html'%}
{%block main%}
<div class="container-xxl d-flex justify-content-center">
   <div class="container-fluid" style='background-color:aquamarine;'></div>
   <div class="container-fluid" style='background-color:rgba(190, 90, 230, 0.308); height:10em;'></div>
   <div class="container-fluid" style='background-color:aquamarine;'></div>
</div>
<div class="container-xxl d-flex justify-content-center">
   <form action='' method="POST">
      {%csrf_token%}
      <input type='text' name='isbn' placeholder="ISBN-13 Number...">
      <button type='submit'>Add</button>
   </form>
</div>
<div class="container-xxl d-flex justify-content-center" id='table'>
   <table class='table table-hover'>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Kategorie</th>
            <th>Seitenzahl</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         {%for book in book_table%}
         <!--tr onClick()-->
            <tr onClick='get_element_ID("{{book.id}}")'>
               <td id="{{book.id}}">{{book.id}}</td>
               <td>{{book.title}}</td>
               <td>{{book.author}}</td>
               <td>{{book.kategorie}}</td>
               <td>{{book.seitenzahl}}</td>
            </tr>
         {%endfor%}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <p>footer</p>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tfoot>
   </table>
</div>
<script>
   function get_element_ID(id){
      var book_id = document.getElementById(id);
      console.log(book_id);
   }
</script>
{%endblock main%}
```

### Output console

[image]